# Threading causes unexpected crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, locks

I have no idea what the issue is here but when I run my code on OS X, it works fine but on Linux my program will not run.

Here is my code:

```
Thread() {
                       - some other code - 
           randLane1 = rand() % 16; 
           randLane2 = rand() % 16; 

           while(randLane1 == randLane2) {
               randLane2 = rand() % 16; 
           }
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
           // if Rouge picked a lane that has already been fired at, look for a free lane
           while(Gallery->Get(randLane1) != white) {
              pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
              randLane1 = rand() % 16; 
              pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
           }   
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);

}
```

Now here is the kicker, if I remove `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);` and `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);`, it will run without issue. But what is causing the error? If I am to simply opening and closing a lock with no possibility on deadlock, what is the issue?

And to further add to my confusion if I place my `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);` right after my `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);` it will work fine.

Note: Within my code `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);` serves a purpose, it is placed further down to perform operations that are not show in the code above. I was debugging my error and realized it didn't even work past the for loop.

If anyone has any idea where my issues lies, that would be great.

Comment: How does it crash? Have you tried running it in a debugger, e.g. `gdb`?

Comment: Did I miss the declaration of mutexFineLock? It may matter.

Comment: Why do you think that there is no possibility for a deadlock? The switching between threads could be between the two lock calls. And if both threads try to do the same locking but in the recvers order then you will have a deadlock.

Comment: Always unlock your lock in reverse order of locking, otherwise you do have a chance of a dead-lock. Or try to refactor the code so you only need one lock at a time.

Comment: @gurka it doesnt output anything
@RobertJacobs it is `pthread_mutex_t mutexFineLock[12];`
@t.niese that would be the case most of the time but for my example, the locks are clearly distinct at the time so I have no reason to believe a deadlock may be possible

Comment: Lets say we have two threads, A and B. Thread A locks both locks while thread B is blocked waiting for the first lock. Then thread A enters the loop and unlocks the first lock, and is preempted for thread B which gets the first lock and is then blocked waiting for the second lock. Thread A starts running again but can't get the first lock back since thread B now holds it. Deadlock.

Comment: I wanted to know if it was "static", "global", or on the stack. If on the stack, could cause issues. Since you did not modify the source code, I still can't tell.

Comment: @QQCompi If your array has twelve elements, `rand() % 16` is not a good way to produce a valid index.

Comment: I hope pthread_mutex_t mutexFineLock[12] is really [16] or you have another bug.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

First thread has locked mutexFineLock[randLane1=13] then mutexFineLock[randLane2=12] and working.

Second thread has locked mutexFineLock[randLane1=3] then trying to lock mutexFineLock[randLane2=12] which is locked, waiting.

While processing first thread has released mutexFineLock[randLane1=13] then trying to lock mutexFineLock[randLane1=13%16=3] which is locked by second thread. Waiting.

Finally everybody's waiting because of deadlock.

When you unlock randLane2 immediately second thread does not have to wait, so it works fine.

This is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You create a deadlock with itself. (at least as long as you don't show us your mutex definition).

```
    while(Gallery->Get(randLane1) != white) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
        randLane1 = rand() % 16; <---------------- PHAIL
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
    }
```

If `randLane1` is equal to `randLane2` you try to relock the same mutex again.

Avoid deadlock due to wrong ordering of locks

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane2]);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
```

Retry to get a different lane1 and 2.
EDIT: changed randLane2 to 1.

```
    while(Gallery->Get(randLane1) != white) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
        randLane1 = rand() % 16;
        while(randLane1 == randLane2) { // retry
           randLane1 = rand() % 16; 
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexFineLock[randLane1]);
    }
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, do you know any way to overcome this deadlock?

Comment: Yes, you can retry it, also fix the lock/unlock ordering.

Comment: @QQCompi, small bug, change the retry to randLane1.

Answer (score 0):

A classic illustration of deadlock. The order of unlocking is not the reversed order of locking. `lock(m1); lock(m2); unlock(m1)` is a straight-from-the-book recipe for disaster. You should always unlock mutexes (or other locks) in the reverse order of their locking.